# Clang complete not working for unsaved files?

Tags: c++, clang, code-completion, code-complete

I've found code complete is not working (via libclang-c) for unsaved files (but works great for saved files).

Code (not all):

```
// show complete options
void showComplete(CXTranslationUnit TU, char *src_filename, unsigned filesize, CXUnsavedFile *file, int line, int column)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "TU=%p, file=%s complete at line=%i, column=%i\n", &TU, src_filename, line, column);

    CXCodeCompleteResults *results =
        clang_codeCompleteAt(TU, src_filename, line, column, file, (file == NULL ? 0 : 1), clang_defaultCodeCompleteOptions());

    if (results) {
        fprintf(stderr, "results=[%p, count=%i]\n", results->Results, results->NumResults);

        /* Sort the code-completion results based on the typed text. */
      clang_sortCodeCompletionResults(results->Results, results->NumResults);

      for (int i = 0; i < results->NumResults; i++)
        print_completion_result(results->Results + i, stdout);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "no complete results\n");
    }

    clang_disposeCodeCompleteResults(results);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Starting ----" << std::endl;

    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(false, false);
    char * filename = argv[1];

    fprintf(stderr, "\ncommand-line file: %s =============\n", filename);
    CXTranslationUnit commandLineTu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, filename, 0, 0, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
    showComplete(commandLineTu, filename, 0, NULL, 1, 72);
    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(commandLineTu);

    // unsaved file tu
    fprintf(stderr, "\nunsaved file =============\n");
    CXUnsavedFile *unsavedFile = new CXUnsavedFile;
    unsavedFile->Filename = "temp.cpp";
    unsavedFile->Contents = "struct TempStruct { int a; bool b; }; int main() { TempStruct str; str. /*complete here*/ return 1; }";
    CXTranslationUnit in_memory_tu = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, unsavedFile->Filename, NULL, 0, unsavedFile, 1, CXTranslationUnit_None);
    int column = strchr(unsavedFile->Contents, '.') - unsavedFile->Contents + 1 + 1; // + 1 (length of '.') + 1 (next symbol)
    showComplete(in_memory_tu, (char*)unsavedFile->Filename, strlen(unsavedFile->Contents), unsavedFile, 1, column);

    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(in_memory_tu);
    clang_disposeIndex(index);

    return 0;
}
```

Source file (saved file, is exactly equals to unsaved file content):

```
struct TempStruct { int a; bool b; }; int main() { TempStruct str; str. /*complete here*/ return 1; }
```

Output:

```
Starting ----

command-line file: ../test/test_complete.cpp =============
TU=0x7fff5d75aaf0, file=../test/test_complete.cpp complete at line=1, column=72
results=[0x7fec7b509510, count=5]
FieldDecl:{ResultType int}{TypedText a} (35) FieldDecl:{ResultType bool}{TypedText b} (35)
CXXMethod:{ResultType TempStruct &}{TypedText operator=}{LeftParen(}{Placeholder const tempStruct &}{RightParen )} (34)
StructDecl:{TypedText TempStruct}{Text ::} (75)
CXXDestructor:{ResultType void}{TypedText ~TempStruct}{LeftParen(}{RightParen )} (34)

unsaved file =============
TU=0x7fff5d75aaf0, file=temp.cpp complete at line=1, column=72
results=[0x7fec7b5043d0, count=0]
```

Any thoughts what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot to set unsavedFile->Length. Even source files are text files you have to set length implicitly (f.e. `unsavedFiles->Length = strlen(unsavedFile->Contents);` )